# Do children (to the age of 15) travel free with their parents on Graz public transport?

Tags: public-transport, children, austria

I'm having trouble getting my head around these rules from https://www.verbundlinie.at/en/tickets-fares/discounts/families:

> Parents travelling together with their children in a public means of
> transport in Styria qualify for a family discount:
>
> - The parents own a valid network ticket: in this case, the registered children travel for free up to the age of 15.
> - The parents do not have a ticket yet: in this case they qualify for a 38% discount on 1 to 6-hour tickets and 24-hour tickets in the
>   Styrian network fare system. In this case children also travel for
>   free until the age of 15.

It then goes on to talk about a Styrian family card (which I don't have).

If I just get on a tram with my 9-year old and buy a 1 hr ticket for myself, does my child travel for free?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tl;dr: **No**, you cannot just get on a train with your child and make use of this discount.

---

The [German-language version of that website](https://www.verbundlinie.at/tickets/ermaessigungen/familien) contains more detailed information:

> Bei gemeinsamen Fahrten mit Kindern gibt es im steirischen Verbundtarif die Familienermäßigung. Zwei Vergünstigungen sind möglich: 1) Die Begleitpersonen haben bereits eine gültige Verbundfahrkarte: Dann dürfen die eingetragenen Kinder bis zum vollendeten 15. Lebensjahr gratis mitfahren. 2) Die Begleitpersonen haben noch keine Fahrkarte: Dann zahlen sie bei gemeinsamen Fahrten mit den Kindern bei Stundenkarten und 24-Stunden-Karten um rund 38 Prozent weniger. Die Kinder fahren auch in diesem Fall bis 15 gratis mit.

This is basically just a translation of what you wrote, but the German site goes on to specify:

> Als Berechtigungsausweis benötigt jede Begleitperson den kostenlosen "ZWEI UND MEHR-Steirischen Familienpass".
> Diese Familienermäßigung gilt für alle eingetragenen Personen: zum Beispiel Mutter oder Vater sowie der/die LebenspartnerIn – und neu – auch die dritte eingetragene Person.
> Auch die Kinder müssen eingetragen sein.

I.e.: people who want to make use of this discount, need to prove their eligibility by showing the Styrian family discount card. Only people who are registered as your family on this card, are eligible for the discount; you can register the parents of the child, an extra partner if applicable, and all children.

So you cannot just hop on a train and expect to get the discount; you need the Styrian family card. Fortunately, you can get it for free:

> Der Familienpass ist kostenlos erhältlich: Referat Familie, Erwachsenenbildung und Frauen; Karmeliterplatz 2, 8010 Graz; +43 316 877-3927; [www.zweiundmehr.steiermark.at](http://www.zweiundmehr.steiermark.at)